# How do I merge *args with default options hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I have a method that accepts an `*args` hash which should be merged with a default options hash:

```
def bt_navbar(*args, &block)
  options = {
    inverse: false,
    fixed: false,
  }.with_indifferent_access.merge!(args.extract_options!)
  # ...
end
```

Because I don't know whether the user of the method likes to use `keys` or `strings` when passing the options, I use `[].with_indifferent_access`.

Is this a good pattern, or is there a better and more established one?

Comment: hmm.. I personally prefer to use `symbolize_keys`

Comment: Also consider using reverse_merge. Otherwise the short answer to your question seems to be "basically yes", but I let the experts out there speak.

Comment: 1) using string as keys is unidiomatic Ruby, so I wouldn't lose a second to manage it. 2) why `*args`? and not `def bt_navbar(args, options={})` and you remove that ugly `extract_options!` part? we'd need more details on the arguments to see which is the best approach.

Comment: @tokland: What if there are no arguments but only options, or sometimes there are and also some options?

Comment: if there are only options: `def fun(options = {})`. If you have more positional arguments: `def fun(arg1, arg2,  options = {})`. You only use `extract_options` when you don't know exactly how many positional arguments you'll have; personally I dislike this kind of signatures (though I know Rails use it a lot), they are confusing.

Comment: a pity you didn't get more answers, it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have two positional arguments. This is what I'd write:

```
def bt_navbar(arg1, arg2, options = {}, &block)
  options.reverse_update({
    inverse: false,
    fixed: false,
  })

  # body
end
```

1. I wouldn't bother to support string keys.
2. `Hash#reverse_update` is part of *active_support*, but it's simple to implement your own method (maybe with a name like `defaults`?).

Comment: Uh-oh, let me talk back to that un-idiomatic argument. Using strings as keys, is, imho, perfectly OK. We shouln't be creating a taboo around this. In cases where there is a limited number of small strings known in advance, using symbols is great. But otherwise, using strings is perfectly OK, and a practice that should be recommended.

Comment: I mean, I agree that Josh's case over here is ripe for Symbols, but let's not create impression that use of Strings as Hash keys is bad practice or something.

Comment: @Boris: Added a "IMO", not that I have any authority on the matter. My rationale is: this seems one of the cases where symbols fit perfectly. If we use strings everywhere where a symbol will do, why use symbols at all?

Comment: "In cases where there is a limited number of small strings known in advance" -> I think we're saying the same. An options hash is usually that, keys are fixed.

Comment: You saved yourself by saying "usually". Usually is not necessarily. Actually, I am in the process of writing a program where I pass the list of { object => value } pairs representing equations as options to a method :)

Comment: @Boris: I couldn't say without seeing more code, but it's difficult for me to call a {object => value} object an "options hash", which is what we are discussing here. For me an options hash is a convenient way to emulate things like the keyword arguments in python, non-compulsory unordered arguments which usually have a default value. If it's very different from that, well, I'd consider it just a hash with data.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. I'm gladly ignoring any strings as hash keys then.